# Loading UIImagePickerController from subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, subview

I'm trying to load an instance of `UIImagePickerController` from a custom subview. For some reason it doesn't work and keeps giving me:

```
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fde7282bc00> on <UIViewController: 0x7fde6f507f00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Here's a skeleton of what my code looks like:

**View Controller**

```
let subview = SubView()
// Subview params...
subview.parent = self
self.view.addSubview(subview)
```

**Subview**

```
class SubView: UIView, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    var parent = UIViewController()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        let add = UIButton()
        // add params...
        add.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addImg(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(add)
    }

    func addImg(_ sender: UIButton) {

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        parent.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            // Do stuff with image

        }

    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current `rootController` using `UIApplication`. This is my working code. It will find the rootController and check if it is type of `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController`

```
if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {

    if rootController is UINavigationController {
        if let navigationController = rootController as? UINavigationController {
            if let topViewController = navigationController.topViewController {
                topViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // is a view controller
        rootController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @AntersBear it works? please mark as correct answer ;)